# Hide some html element if WooCommerce cart is empty

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, cart

I have a menu cart icon in my header. Currently, the menu cart icon is always visible. I would like it to be visible only if there are items in the cart. So I'm trying to make it so the menu cart icon is hidden if the cart is empty.

I tried:

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
    
    if ( WC()->cart->is_empty() ) {
        
        echo '<style type="text/css">.elementor-widget-hfe-cart{ display: none; }</style>';
    
    }

});
```

But it doesn't work. Why?

---

**EDIT**

It turns out my hosting provider turned on caching for my website a while back therefore I could't see the changes. The code snippet works fine...

Comment: I am tried both code in localhost with storefront theme both is working so it's may css issue. give !important with display: none

Comment: It turns out my hosting provider turned on caching for my website therefore I could't see the changes. The code snippet works fine...

Answer (score 0):

You can check the size of the cart using `sizeof` function check below code.

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {    
    if ( sizeof( WC()->cart->get_cart() ) < 1 ) {
        echo '<style type="text/css">.elementor-widget-hfe-cart{ display: none; }</style>';
    }
});
```